# Syntax help in shell scripting

Tags: syntax

I am a newbee in shell scripting and am learning it from online tutorial website .
In a particular code I came across the following line :

```
[ -z "${starkisland}" ]             && { echo "`basename $0`: ERROR: starkisland environment variable not defined !" ; exit 2 ; }
```

Here I see `[ -z "${starkisland}" ]` is an `if` condition meaning if the file `starkisland` is  of zero size and the part after `&&` is like the part that is to be executed if the condition is `true`. But I guess `&&` is the symbol for `AND` condition, if I am not wrong.
Can anyone help me in understanding the statement and logic behind writing like this if `&&` is the `AND` condition.?

Answer (score 0):

You should read this

```
if [ CONDITION ] && {ACTION1} || {ACTION2}
```

as

```
If CONDITION then ACTION1 else ACTION2
```

In fact these are not logical operators, these flow control operators

&& means "execute if exit code is 0"

|| means "execute if exit code is not 0"